# What should I be doing now to get a good recommendation letter as a graduate student?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, recommendation-letter

I am currently doing a Master's degree in applied mathematics. I am worried though about after I complete my degree and I apply to another graduate school for an applied mathematics PhD program. While I have a good relationship with my supervisor an expect to get a good recommendation letter, most graduate schools and research award applications require three.

**My question is what should I be doing now to ensure that I can easily get good recommendation letters when I graduate?**

Right now I spend most of my time doing research which by it's nature in my field is a solo activity in collaboration with my supervisor. The rest of my time is being a teaching assistant, and doing a few extra circulars. I want to start working on getting good recommendations while I still have time before I graduate.

**More Personal Notes**

- I am in my first year, started September 2017.
- Things I do outside of research and being a teaching assistant include being part of my school's graduate society, and mentoring undergraduate students in the department.

Comment: Do you not take classes from other faculty in your Master's program?  As well as a separate professor you're TAing for?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this.  Yes I do.

Comment: In part, the requirement of 3 letters tests exactly whether you do interact with more than just your advisor. Genuinely "solo work", unless it is ground-breaking, is not necessarily compelling in itself.

Comment: Okay then in a field where it is common for papers to be authored by one or two people how can I work in the meantime to show that I am a team player.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to get a good teaching reference if you're working as a TA.  Most departments have one or more faculty who supervise graduate student TA's.  If you're actually leading a recitation section or teaching a class, you should ask this person if they would be willing to write a recommendation letter addressing your teaching and you should invite them to observe you in the classroom environment.  A good letter of this support together with good student evaluations will make a strong case for your ability as an instructor.